# Do I need "being" or not?

Tags: grammaticality

I am wondering if this sentence is correct as written:

> Being possessing all these traits, I have a strong belief that I am competent for this position.

Is "being" required at the beginning of this sentence?

Comment: Please save the code markup for sites where code is needed, like Stack Overflow. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not correct. You could say:

Being in possession of all these traits, I have a strong belief that I am competent for this position.

I wouldn't use possessing directly, (the other construction is more formal), but then, I wouldn't express the sentence that way in the first place. Assuming it's from a job application letter, I'd list my knowledge, skills and experience, but I wouldn't say " I have a strong belief that I am competent for this position.", since it's redundant (otherwise you wouldn't be applying for the job). I'd let the person reading my job application letter draw his own conclusions about how competent I was. I would, however, end my job application letter on a positive note, by saying "Thank you for considering my application. I am available for interview at your earliest convenience."

Comment: Can I use possessing directly? which expression is better compare with "Being in possession of"?

Comment: @user2196452  See edited answer.

Comment: Yes, you can also say "Possessing all these traits, I have a strong belief that I am competent for this position" (from a language point of view). What would be appropriate in your context would be better asked on [Workplace SE](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/).